# Count the number of months between two events when a condition occurs in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I'm working in Pyspark and I need to count the number of months between two events when a condition is met.

Next I show how my table is, so that you understand me better. This is my initial dataframe.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row, Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from datetime import datetime, date

row = Row("id", "start", "condition")
df = sc.parallelize([
    row(1, "2015-01-31", 0),
    row(1, "2015-02-28", 0),
    row(1, "2015-03-31", 0),
    row(1, "2015-04-30", 0),
    row(1, "2015-05-31", 1),
    row(1, "2015-06-30", 1)
]).toDF().withColumn("start", col("start").cast("date"))

## +---+----------+----------+
## | id|     start| condition| 
## +---+----------+----------+
## |  1|2015-01-31|         0|
## |  1|2015-02-28|         0|
## |  1|2015-03-31|         0|
## |  1|2015-04-30|         0|
## |  1|2015-05-31|         1|
## |  1|2015-06-30|         1|
## +---+----------+----------+
```

I want this result:

```
## +---+----------+----------+------------------+       
## | id|     start| condition| Months_between|
## +---+----------+----------+---------------+
## |  1|2015-01-31|         0|              4|
## |  1|2015-02-28|         0|              3|
## |  1|2015-03-31|         0|              2|
## |  1|2015-04-30|         0|              1|
## |  1|2015-05-31|         1|              0|
## |  1|2015-06-30|         1|              0|
## +---+----------+----------+---------------+
```

I want to know How many months have passed between one row and another in which the condition has gone from 0 to 1. If the condition never goes to 1, it should be 0.
The sample has an id but there are many id for each date.

I have thought about making a window but I don't know how to get the number of months. I had thought something like that:

```
max_days = (df.select(max("start")).collect()[0][0] - df.select(min("start")).collect()[0][0]).days
days = lambda i: i * 86400
window = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(col("start").cast("long")).rangeBetween(days(max_days), 0)
```

Thanks! It works:

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
    'Months_between', 
    F.when(
        F.col('condition') == 0, 
        F.months_between(
            F.min(
                F.when(F.col('condition') == 1, F.col('start'))
            ).over(Window.partitionBy('id')), 
            F.col('start')
        ).cast('int')
    ).otherwise(0)
)
```

but i find a problem when i have this example. when the value changes between 0 and 1 several times.

```
| id|     start|condition|Months_between|
+---+----------+---------+------------------+
|  1|2015-01-31|        0|              2|
|  1|2015-02-28|        0|              1|
|  1|2015-03-31|        1|              0|
|  1|2015-04-30|        1|              0|
|  1|2015-05-31|        0|             -1|
|  1|2015-06-30|        1|              0|
+---+----------+---------+-----------------+
```

On the date 2015-05-31 it should take the value 1, but when searching for the minimum it gets the value -1. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the earliest date where condition = 1 for each id, and get the months between that date and the current row using `months_between`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'next_start',
    F.first(
        F.when(F.col('condition') == 1, F.col('start')),
        ignorenulls=True
    ).over(
        Window.partitionBy('id')
              .orderBy('start')
              .rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)
    )
).withColumn(
    'Months_between', 
    F.when(
        F.col('condition') == 0, 
        F.months_between(
            F.col('next_start'), 
            F.col('start')
        ).cast('int')
    ).otherwise(0)
).drop('next_start')

df2.show() 
+---+----------+---------+--------------+
| id|     start|condition|Months_between|
+---+----------+---------+--------------+
|  1|2015-01-31|        0|             2|
|  1|2015-02-28|        0|             1|
|  1|2015-03-31|        1|             0|
|  1|2015-04-30|        1|             0|
|  1|2015-05-31|        0|             1|
|  1|2015-06-30|        1|             0|
+---+----------+---------+--------------+
```